# Why is Entity Framework trying to update my child entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server project where we have a `Game` and it has related child entities such as `Venue`, `Season` and `GameType`.

```
public Game()
{
    Results = new HashSet<Result>();
}

public int GameId { get; set; }
public int SeasonId { get; set; }
public int VenueId { get; set; }
public int GameTypeId { get; set; }

[Required] 
public DateTime GameDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
public int BuyIn { get; set; }

[Timestamp] 
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

public virtual Season Season { get; set; }
public virtual Venue Venue { get; set; }
public virtual GameType GameType { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
```

I have a repo that is injected into my page to handle the update:

```
...
public async Task UpdateGame(Game game)
{
    using (var context = _suttonPokerDbContext.CreateDbContext())
    {
        context.Games.Update(game);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
...

@page "/Settings/Games/EditGame/{GameId:int}"
@using SuttonPokerBlazor.Components
@using SuttonPokerBlazor.Models
@using SuttonPokerBlazor.Repositories.Interfaces
@inject IGameRepository gamesRepository
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject ISeasonRepository seasonsRepository
@inject IVenueRepository venueRepository
@inject IGameTypeRepository gameTypeRepository

@if (Game != null)
{
    <h3>Add new game</h3>

    <EditForm Model="@Game" OnValidSubmit="Save">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Season" class="form-label">Season</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <InputSelect @bind-Value="@Game.SeasonId" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (Season season in seasons)
                    {
                    <option value="@season.SeasonId">@season.SeasonDescription</option>
                    }
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Game.SeasonId)" />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Season" class="form-label">Venue</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="@Game.VenueId" class="form-control">
                @foreach (Venue venue in venues)
                    {
                    <option value="@venue.VenueId">@venue.VenueName</option>
                    }
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Game.VenueId)" />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Season" class="form-label">Game Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="@Game.GameTypeId" class="form-control">
                @foreach (GameType gameType in gameTypes)
                    {
                    <option value="@gameType.GameTypeId">@gameType.GameTypeDescription</option>
                    }
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Game.GameTypeId)" />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="GameDate" class="form-label">Game Date</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <InputDate class="form-control" @bind-Value="Game.GameDate" />
        </div>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Game.GameDate)" />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="BuyIn" class="form-label">Buy In</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value="Game.BuyIn" />
        </div>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Game.BuyIn)" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="Cancel">Back</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="Delete">Delete</button>
        </div>

</EditForm>

    <Confirm @ref="DeleteConfirmation" ConfirmationChanged="ConfirmDelete"
         ConfirmationMessage=@($"Are you sure you want to delete {Game.GameDate} - {Game.GameType.GameTypeDescription}?")>
    </Confirm>
}
else
{
    <h3>Not found</h3>
}


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int GameId { get; set; }

    public Game Game { get; set; }
    ConfirmBase DeleteConfirmation { get; set; }
    List<Season> seasons { get; set; }
    List<Venue> venues { get; set; }
    List<GameType> gameTypes { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Game = await gamesRepository.GetGame(GameId);
        seasons = await seasonsRepository.GetSeasons();
        venues = await venueRepository.GetVenues();
        gameTypes = await gameTypeRepository.GetGameTypes();
    }

    private async Task Save()
    {
        await gamesRepository.UpdateGame(Game);
    }

    private void Cancel()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Settings/Games/");
    }

    private void Delete()
    {
        DeleteConfirmation.Show();
    }

    private async void ConfirmDelete(bool deleteConfirmed)
    {
        if (deleteConfirmed)
        {
            await gamesRepository.DeleteGame(Game);
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Settings/Games/");
        }
    }
}
```

However, when the `Game` entity is updated it sets the Id of `Season`, `GameType` and/or `Venue` back to what they were before the update occurred.

For example:

Pre `SaveChangesAsync()`:

[image]

Post `SaveChangesAsync()`:

[image]

SQL produced:

[image]

In the SQL above, my assumption was that I would only see a update request to my Game entity. Why is it making updates to the other related tables and then why is it reverting anything that was changed back to what it was pre Save?

Any other changes to things like dates or strings is persisted as expected. It just seems that where I've used a drop down `<InputSelect>` this effect is taking place.

**Update:**

This is an updated version of my repo that seems to work but
Caius Jard was asking why I was doing what had fixed my issue. I'm happy to correct something if what I've done is incorrect for some reason:

```
public class GameRepository : IGameRepository
    {
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<SuttonPokerDbContext> _suttonPokerDbContext;

        public GameRepository(IDbContextFactory<SuttonPokerDbContext> suttonPokerDbContext)
        {
            _suttonPokerDbContext = suttonPokerDbContext;
        }

        public async Task<Game> GetGame(int GameId)
        {
            using (var context = _suttonPokerDbContext.CreateDbContext())
            {
                return await context.Games.Include(q => q.Results).Include(q => q.GameType).Include(q => q.Venue).Include(q => q.Season).FirstOrDefaultAsync(q => q.GameId == GameId); ;
            }
        }

        public async Task<List<Game>> GetGames()
        {
            using (var context = _suttonPokerDbContext.CreateDbContext())
            {
                return await context.Games.Include(q => q.GameType).Include(q => q.Venue).Include(q => q.Season).OrderByDescending(q => q.GameDate).ToListAsync();
            }
        }

        public async Task<Game> AddGame(Game game)
        {
            using (var context = _suttonPokerDbContext.CreateDbContext())
            {
                context.Games.Add(game);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                
                return game;
            }
        }

        public async Task<Game> UpdateGame(Game game)
        {
            using (var context = _suttonPokerDbContext.CreateDbContext())
            {
                // First we need to get the game from the database as we need to see if it's been modified already
                Game dbGame = await context.Games.Include(q => q.Results).Include(q => q.GameType).Include(q => q.Venue).Include(q => q.Season).FirstOrDefaultAsync(q => q.GameId == game.GameId);
                // Compare the byte arrays
                if (!dbGame.RowVersion.SequenceEqual(game.RowVersion))
                {
                    game = dbGame;
                    return game;
                }
                else
                {
                    // We have to detach the dbGame version otherwise we get a conflict of tracked games.
                    context.Entry(dbGame).State = EntityState.Detached;
                    context.Entry(game).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return game;
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task DeleteGame(Game game)
        {
            using (var context = _suttonPokerDbContext.CreateDbContext())
            {
                context.Remove(game);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you may try to explicitly set `Venue` to null, so context would not know anything about child property and it would use only `VenueId`. Same with other navigational properties

Comment: This almost works actually @DthToRussia but once the code returns to the page from the repository I get an `'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` error. I can see in the watch that the `Venue`, `Season` and `GameType` are `null` and they aren't refreshed after the save. It feels a bit hacky to null them at the point of save and then have to fetch them from the context?

Comment: Not to sure but, I think your gamesRepository.GetGame(gameID) might not be how you're trying to use it. Game already has all the objects you want in it but, you're retrieving them again though. I think your SQL needs some Join statements if I'm understanding this right.

Comment: Why are you calling Update()? Post your OnModelCreating and the definitions of the other entities, and the create scripts for the db tables

Comment: I was following a tutorial online @CaiusJard which perhaps is using a more simple model than I'm trying to create. Using `context.Entry(game).State = EntityState.Modified` seems to do the trick rather than `Udpate()`. I thought they did the same thing really but having read https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/modifying-data it would seem that `Update()` will track all of the children too creating the issue I was having.

Comment: But you're not supposed to have to fiddle with the change tracker to trick it into thinking something is modified, unless you've renewed the context and it's hence forgotten about the entity. Blazor server is a special case for the way you have to treat contexts to prevent them being long lived, but the typical use case would be to download the entity you want to update, change it (copy data out of some model that drives the view) and save it. If you're using the entity from the database as the model for the view it'd explain why you're fudging a modified state, but it's an atypical approach

Comment: I think I am renewing the context (still learning). I inject `IDbContextFactory` on the repository and then call `CreateDbContext()` on my context. I wanted to try and implement `RowVersion` on records to check for concurrency and if I just used an injected context ranther than `IDbContextFactory` I could not check the differences on my `RowVersion` property as it would not refresh from the Db. I will post an updated version of my working repo and see what you think.

Comment: Added the updated repo @CaiusJard.